# How to get the xml node based on a String values using XSL?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a string variable which has multiple node refs numbers with comma separated ex : test_variable = #id1,#id147,#id168

Now I need to get all the xml nodes where reference numbers of the above string variable matches in a variable.

So that i cam Show up data of only those nodes which have matched the above criteria.

I am confused how to spilt and form the condition.Please help

```
<xsl:variable name="test_variable" select="substring-after($vMinMaxVar,'|')"/>
<xsl:message><xsl:text>PrintingTesting_Variable:-</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$test_variable"/></xsl:message>
```

so if i print the above line . I would be having an value i.e. 
PrintingTesting_Variable:-#id1,#id147,#id168 (This ouput can be single value or Multivalued with Commaseprated).

Now i need to go back to xml and filter the xml nodes only which is having only these Reference numbers inside its tag

Sample Xml Content for Reference :-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sample xmlns="http://www.sample.org/Schemas/xyzwSchema"
 language="en-us" time="11:16:55" schemaVersion="6" author="John" date="2019-07-26">
<Process id="id234" instancedRef="#id1" >
<UserData id="id41">
<UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"></UserValue>
</Process>

<Process id="id235" instancedRef="#id23" >
<UserData id="id42">
<UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"></UserValue>
</Process>

<Process id="id236" instancedRef="#id147" >
<UserData id="id43">
<UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"></UserValue>
</Process>

<Process id="id237" instancedRef="#id168" >
<UserData id="id44">
<UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"></UserValue>
</Process>

<Process id="id238" instancedRef="#id196" >
<UserData id="id45">
<UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"></UserValue>
</Process>

<Process id="id239" instancedRef="#id241" >
<UserData id="id46">
<UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"></UserValue>
</Process>
</Sample>
```

I expect a output where a Variable holds all the those filtererd nodes.

Comment: Are you really restricted to XSLT 1? If so, which XSLT 1 processor exactly do you use? Does it support an extension function to tokenize your a string, like http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html?

Comment: Your XML is missing closing tags for `UserData`.

Comment: *"I expect a output where a Variable holds all the those filtererd nodes."* There is no such thing. Variables cease to exist when processing ends. The output must be a document (XML, HTML or text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML (well-formed!!!)**

```
<Sample xmlns="http://www.sample.org/Schemas/xyzwSchema" language="en-us" time="11:16:55" schemaVersion="6" author="John" date="2019-07-26">
  <Process id="id234" instancedRef="#id1">
    <UserData id="id41"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
  <Process id="id235" instancedRef="#id23">
    <UserData id="id42"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
  <Process id="id236" instancedRef="#id147">
    <UserData id="id43"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
  <Process id="id237" instancedRef="#id168">
    <UserData id="id44"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
  <Process id="id238" instancedRef="#id196">
    <UserData id="id45"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
  <Process id="id239" instancedRef="#id241">
    <UserData id="id46"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
</Sample>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://www.sample.org/Schemas/xyzwSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="references">#id1,#id147,#id168</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/ns:Sample">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ns:Process[contains(concat($references, ','), concat(@instancedRef, ','))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sample xmlns="http://www.sample.org/Schemas/xyzwSchema">
  <Process id="id234" instancedRef="#id1">
    <UserData id="id41"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
  <Process id="id236" instancedRef="#id147">
    <UserData id="id43"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
  <Process id="id237" instancedRef="#id168">
    <UserData id="id44"/>
    <UserValue title="Mfg0allocated_time" type="real" value="23.4"/>
  </Process>
</Sample>
```

Comment: Hi Micheal,Really thanks your suggestion It really worked for me.